# Facebook login using RxSwift

Tags: facebook, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm trying to implement the following RxSwift example:

Login in with facebook in my application -> retrieve the user information -> retrieve user's profile photo.

I have these three functions and they must be executed in this order: requestAccess() -> fetchUserInformation() -> fetchUserPhoto()

```
func requestAccess() -> Observable<(ACAccount)> {
    return create { observer -> Disposable in
        let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
        let accountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook)
        let dictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [ACFacebookAppIdKey:"***APPID***", ACFacebookPermissionsKey:["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]]

        accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(accountType, options: dictionary) { granted, error in
            if granted == false || error != nil {
                sendError(observer, error ?? UnknownError)
            } else {
                let accounts = accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(accountType)
                let account = accounts.last as! ACAccount
                sendNext(observer, account)
                sendCompleted(observer)
            }
        }

        return AnonymousDisposable({})
    }
}

func fetchUserInformation(account: ACAccount) -> Observable<User> {
    return create { observer -> Disposable in
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/me")
        let request = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook, requestMethod: .GET, URL: url, parameters: nil)
        request.account = account

        request.performRequestWithHandler { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if data == nil || response == nil {
                sendError(observer, error ?? UnknownError)
            } else {
                let result: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
                let user = User()
                user.updateInformationWithJSON(result! as! JSONObject)

                sendNext(observer, user)
                sendCompleted(observer)
            }
        }

        return AnonymousDisposable({})
    }
}

func fetchUserPhoto(user: User) -> Observable<AnyObject> {
    return create { observer -> Disposable in
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/***myid***/picture")
        let params = ["redirect":"false", "height":"200", "width":"200"]

        let request = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook, requestMethod: .GET, URL: url, parameters: params)
        request.account = SocialController.account

        request.performRequestWithHandler { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if data == nil || response == nil {
                sendError(observer, error ?? UnknownError)
            } else {
                let result: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)                    
                sendNext(observer, result!)
                sendCompleted(observer)
            }
        }

        return AnonymousDisposable({})
    }
}
```

I already tried to implement this flow but it doesn't feel right. What is the best way to solve this problem?

```
        requestAccess()
        >- subscribeNext { account in
            fetchUserInformation(account)
                >- map { user in return UserViewModel(model: user) }
                >- subscribeNext { viewModel in self.viewModel = viewModel }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `flatMap`?
It's an equivalent to `then` in the JavaScript bluebird or Q world. The difference between `map` and `flatMap` is that `flatMap` *must* return an `Observable<T>` which will then be unwrapped in the following block/closure.

```
requestAccess()
   >- flatMap{ account in
      return fetchUserInformation(account)
   }
   >- map { user in 
      return UserViewModel(model:user)
   }
   >- subscribeNext { viewModel in
      self.viewModel = viewModel
   }
```

Tidbit #1: Consider using `unowned self` when referencing `self` to avoid a retain cycle.

Tidbit #2: These two are pretty much the same thing.

```
flatMap { return just("hello") }
  >- subscribeNext{ greeting in println(greeting) }

map { return "hello" } 
  >- subscribeNext{ greeting in println(greeting) }
```

Comment: Thanks Max Alexander! Your solution solves my problem :)

Comment: No problem! I've found that adding "rx_" as a prefix to your methods is a good idea so you know that method is going to wrap your return value as an Observable. Instead of `fetchInformation`, I name it as `rx_fetchInformation`. It helps when you have a lot of `flatMap` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
private
func requestFacebookAccess(_ viewController: UIViewController) -> Observable<LoginManagerLoginResult?> {

    return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in

        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: viewController, handler: { result, error in
            observer.onNext(result)
            observer.onCompleted()

        })

        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```